# Png compression and image resizing

Tags: .net, png, image-resizing, imageresizer

Is there a way / plugin to help the image resizer with png compression?

I have a png image that I use in navigation and would like to keep it as small as possible. The original image has width 200px and size 38kb. I need to resize it down to 150px. Once I do so using the image resizer the size goes up to 150kb.

Originally the image was compressed using http://tinypng.org/

Comment: Can you check your numbers here, I think you have a typo that makes it impossible to understand what you really mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, [the PrettyGifs plugin offers excellent octree quantization for both PNG and GIF images.](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/prettygifs)

Use `&colors=256`, `&colors=128`, etc to adjust the bit depth. You can also preserve the existing color palette with `preservePalette=true`.

Note that advanced PNG compression optimizations (such as offered by smush.it, tinypng, etc) require an *additional* 150-400MB of RAM and take 10-20 seconds to perform - for obvious reasons you wouldn't want that to happen during a dynamic request. ImageResizer tries to finish each request under 250ms.

Hand-optimizing *PNG/GIF* CSS sprites and site-wide icons is usually going to give you a smaller file size that ImageResizer can, although it's nearly impossible to beat for photographic data.

Of course, [with the WebP plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/webp) installed, ImageResizer will wipe the floor with the competition.